# Validation not working with saveMany

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Validations are not working with saveMany for all values.its only working for first value. I am using translate behavior.

My code:

```
public function admin_add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->FaqCategory->create();            
        $this->request->data['FaqCategory']['name'] = Inflector::slug($this->request->data['FaqCategory']['name'], $replacement = '-');
        if ($this->FaqCategory->saveMany($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The faq category has been saved', 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The faq category could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $languages = $this->Language->getlangs();
    $this->set('langs', $languages);
}
```

Comment: Is there any error?If yes then please post it here.and can you put $this->request->data dump

Comment: use $this->set( $this->request->data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$this->FaqCategory->saveMany($this->request->data, array('validate' => true));`